# Error in OnBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating simple screen which has one textview and button with the use of Recyclerview and Cardview.
Xml code is ready but I dont know what to write in my OnBindViewHolder class which is in my Adapter.

**This is My Adapter for RecycleView**

```
 public class PaperAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> papers;
    public TextView paperName;


    public PaperAdapter(List<String> papers) {
        this.papers = papers;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            paperName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPaperName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View paperView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.paper_row, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(paperView);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return papers.size();
    }}
```

**This is my MainActivity**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

                        RecyclerView recyclerView;

                        List<String> papers = new ArrayList<>();

                        @Override
                        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                                setContentView(R.layout.activity_paper);

                                papers.add("Paper 1");
                                papers.add("Paper 2");
                                papers.add("Paper 3");
                                papers.add("Paper 4");

                                recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvPapers);
                                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
                                PaperAdapter adapter = new PaperAdapter(papers);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        }

                }
```

**This is my Pagelayout xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#A4C639"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPaperName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="paper 1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="download" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

App is working without writing anything in OnBindViewHolder but its not showing Paper1,Paper2,Paper3 like this list so thats why I need to define textview in OnBindViewHolder but its showing error.Please let me know how to define textview in that and what to write in OnBindViewHolder.Also wanna set OnCLickListner for button so help me in that too.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> [`onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)) is called by [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) to display the data at the specified position. This method should update the contents of the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder.itemView` to reflect the item at the given position.

So you need to use this method to update the contents of the `itemView` to reflect the item at the given position.
As per your question you want to show `TextView` with `Button` in your `RecyclerView`, so you need to implement `onBindViewHolder()` as:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.paperName.setText(papers.get(position));
        holder.download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: Your code to download
            }
        });
    }
```

You also need to give `id` to your `button` as:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/btnDownload"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:text="download" />
```

And update `MyViewHolder` as:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView paperName;
        Button download;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            paperName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPaperName);
            download = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);
        }
    }
```

Simply, copy and paste this code in your `PageAdapter` class:

```
public class PaperAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> papers;
    private Context mContext;

    public PaperAdapter(Context context, List<String> papers) {
        this.papers = papers;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView paperName;
        Button download;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            paperName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPaperName);
            download = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View paperView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.paper_row, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(paperView);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.paperName.setText(papers.get(position));
        holder.download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, papers.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // TODO: Your code to download
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return papers.size();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: You need `Context` to show `Toast`, so pass `Context` in your `MainActivity` as:

```
PaperAdapter adapter = new PaperAdapter(this, papers);
```

Comment: Thank u sir.Now i want to toast the papername  when Onclick download button.Do u know how to do that?

Comment: pass `Context` of `MainActivity`  while creating instance of `PaperAdapter`. I've made an edit to the code.